# In OLS, why is squaring preferred over taking absolute while calculating errors in linear regression?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence, linear-regression, statsmodels

Why do we use the **squared residuals** instead of the **absolute residuals** in **OLS estimation**.

My idea was that we use the square of the error values, so that residuals below the fitted line (which are then negative), would still have to be able to be added up to the positive errors. Otherwise, we could have an error of 0 simply because a huge positive error could cancel with a huge negative error.

So why do we square it, instead of just taking the absolute value? Is that because of the **extra penalty** for higher errors (instead of 2 being 2 times the error of 1, it is 4 times the error of 1 when we square it).

Comment: OLS = ordinary least SQUARES, this corresponds to the normal distribution. Absolute values give a different estimator, median regression, a special case of Quantile Regression.

Comment: This is a statistics question and not a code question.

Comment: My understanding is that historically, because "absolute value" has no continuous derivative, it was considered unacceptable because it could not be used in the symbolic logic of the calculus. Squaring does have a continuous derivative and was considered acceptable. For example, Root Mean Squared Errors (RMSE) is somewhat equivalent to "average magnitude of error", but average magnitude of error involves use of absolute value and was considered unacceptable as a fit statistic.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; questions about machine learning theory & methodology are off-topic here, and should be posted at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that large negative residuals (i.e., points far below the line) are as bad as large positive ones (i.e., points that are high above the line). By squaring the residual values, we treat positive and negative discrepancies in the same way. Why do we sum all the squared residuals? Because we cannot find a single straight line that minimizes all residuals simultaneously. Instead, we minimize the average (squared) residual value.

Comment: Okay. This definitely helped me clearing out some confusion.